# How do you activate classes based on an input list?

Tags: python, list, class

I am making a card game that uses decks, each of which contains many cards. The decks are in a .txt. I am not sure how to transfer the .txt list to a list of class objects for each deck.

```
line_num = 0
    decks = {}
    name = None
    for line in open("Decks.txt", "r"):
        line_num = line_num + 1
        raw_line = line.strip("\n")
        if line_num % 2 == 1:
            name = raw_line
        elif line_num % 2 == 0:
            decks[name] = raw_line.split(", ")
            for item in decks[name]:
```

This is where I need to know how to activate each item in the list as a class object. Once activated, the objects will be added to a list called `player.deck`.

Each card in the deck is a class which contains characteristics like `self.health`, `self.image`, and `self.attack`.

Comment: Can you provide some example? And some code or structure of your class.

Comment: Impossible to help without seeing the class definitions and the file contents.